# How do I trigger a github action from the target branch on incoming pull-request reviews?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm using GitHub actions to automate pull requests to my repositories. In particular, I'd like to run actions whenever a pull request gets a review to automatically label it. Because of this, I'd like to run code from the context of my base branch (similarly to how `pull_request_target` works as a counterpart to `pull_request`).

I've looked at [the events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows), but there doesn't seem to be a `pull_request_review_target` or any similar events that would be the counterpart to `pull_request_review`.

Answer (score 1):

And what's about `submitted` on [`pull_request_review`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_review)

```yaml
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
```

Or maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: ahhh, no this doesn't quite solve my issue. The `pull_request_review` runs from the PR merge branch, but I'm looking for something that would run from the PR base branch, similarly to how `pull_request_target` works